# Xamarin System.ArgumentException: Parameter cannot be null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am still training with Xamarin. Now I got issue that I cannot set object to resource and I am getting this error: reference not set to an instance of object.

What I have done, that I created Activity class. There I create LinearLayout object. Idea is when I click on blue zone object then swipes to another page: vehicle not parked layout. But it doesn't work, I am getting errors.
This is my ZonesActivity class:

```
namespace CustomActionBarParking
    {
        [Activity(Label = "@+id/blueZoneLayout")]

        public class ZonesActivity : Activity
        LinearLayout mBlueZone;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                mBlueZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.blueZoneLayout);
                if (mBlueZone != null)
                {
                    mBlueZone.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
                    {
                        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.vehicle_not_parked);
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "");
                }
}}}
```

And this is my part of zones_list.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="11"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blueZoneLayout"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">
        <TextView
            android:text="M"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Blue zone"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="i"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas why I can't set references to this object's? And also I want to mention that I am calling zones_list layout from MainActivity.cs .
Edit: In throw new ArgumentException I am getting this:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: Parameter cannot be null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mBlueZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.blueZoneLayout);
```

The variable `mBlueZone` will always be null in this case. `FindViewById` looks for `View` that has an `Id` `blueZoneLayout` within the layout that has been set as ContentView of the `Activity`. You need to set the ContentView before infalting Views from it. You should be adding this line

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.zones_list);
```

before

```
mBlueZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.blueZoneLayout);
```

EDIT: The above portion will fix the problem (as per your logic) and work. But this is not the recommended approach for doing it. You should be having a separate `Activity` for Vehicle not Parked Layout.

```
public class LaunchActivity:Activity
{
   protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.zones_list);
        mBlueZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.blueZoneLayout);
            mBlueZone.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof(NotParkedActivity));
                };
     }

}

 public class NotParkedActivity :Activity
{
   protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout. vehicle_not_parked);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have added a better way to do the same. Check my edit